# React Native App Not Loading After Splash Screen on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, mobile-development

I am trying to run a React Native application in my iPhone but after the application gets build from XCode and installed to my device, it opens up with Splash Screen but after that nothing happens.

And after sometime, I get error in XCode. Find the Screenshot of XCode below.

[image]

The error says `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`.

And I am using `React Native` and not `Expo`.

I am using XCode Version 15.2 (15C500b) and Sonoma 14.2.1. And the physical device is iPhone 14 (17.3.1).

I am expecting to run my application on my phone.

Comment: You should check if you are hiding the splash screen or not. 
Are you using react-native-splash-screen for the splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the location ,of the splash screen in the ios/launch_screen file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).